# Filename match with Python regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a text file scraped from my email which contains 1 attachment/mail. The attachment is present under different names with different formats, for example:

```
filename="John_wheeler 11041997 resume.pdf";
filename="Kujal_newResume(1).pdf"; 
filename=JohnKrasinski_Resume.pdf
```

My question is: is there any way to find a RegEx pattern that would start searching from `filename=` and go until the dot character (that separates from file extension)? Getting file extension would be next task, but I can hold that for now.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please provide the data/input you have, the code that you have tried, the expected output and the error you got.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this pattern: `filename="?([^.]+)`

It assumes that dot separates filename from extension.

Explanation:

`filename="?` - match `filename=` literally and tehn match 0 or 1 apostrophe `"`

`([^.]+)` - match one or more characters that is **not** a dot (match everything until dot) and store it in capturing group

Your desired filename will be stored in capturing group.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xmXqeu/2)

**EXTRA**: to capture also file extension, you could use such pattern: `filename="?([^.]+)\.([^";]+)`

Additional thing here is `\.([^";]+)`: matches dot literally with `\.`. Then it matches one or more characters other than `"` or `;` with pattern `[^";]+` and stores it in second capturing gropup.

[Another demo](https://regex101.com/r/xmXqeu/3)

Answer (score 0):

How about the following:

```
(?:filename=)([^\.]*)\.(\w*)
```

This REGEX returns different groups containing the different elements you're interested in.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the output you expect. But this may help. [RegexDemo](https://regex101.com/r/RJD6ZZ/1)

```
(?<=filename=)[\"]?(\w.*[.].*)(?<=\w)[\"]?
```

Or if you want to ignore the file extension:

```
(?<=filename=)[\"]?(\w.*)[\.]
```